# Exit codes from Fortran to Linux

Tags: linux, fortran, environment-variables, exit-code

I need to define the exit codes of my program that is written in Fortran 90, but I'm getting confused on the way.

I read and create NetCDF files, thus some of the error codes are provided by the NetCDF libraries. In order to pass the exit code to the Linux environment variables, I use along the code the `exit(status)` wherever the program is terminated.

But something is going wrong, or I don't understand it at least. If I get an error code from NetCDF, for instance `-49` (variable not found), the program ends and the retrieved value when using `echo $?` is `207`. Why?

If I set some specific exits using `status=-1`, then the `$?` value is `255`.

I have read those linux exit codes depend on the shell, some of them are reserved, there are some called system errors.

Comment: I've seen that the 255 means Exit status out of range (exit takes only integer args in the range 0 - 255). But then, where is that 207 coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unix exit code is unsigned. If you return a negative, it will be implicitly converted.

256-49=207 but this is probably platform-dependent.